# Define a (real valued) variable in TikZ/LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to generate a TikZ image from a `foreach` loop, where some coordinates change within this loop. How can I do something as simple as

```
float x = 0.5;
x += 0.1;
```

in TikZ/LaTeX? I searched on tex.stackexchange and the TikZ manual, but I only found counters (which are integer..).

---

I want to draw a barplot like this one: http://www.statistiker-wg.de/pgf/tutorials/barplot.htm (bottom of the page, pdf file: http://www.statistiker-wg.de/pgf/pics/barplot4.pdf), but I don't want to specify the x coordinates manually.

```
  \definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{92dcec}

  \begin{tikzpicture}

  \draw (0cm,0cm) -- (15.5cm,0cm);  %Abzisse
  \draw (0cm,0cm) -- (0cm,-0.1cm);  %linkes Ende der Abzisse
  \draw (15.5cm,0cm) -- (15.5cm,-0.1cm);  %rechtes Ende der Abzisse

  \draw (-0.1cm,0cm) -- (-0.1cm,4.5cm);  %Ordinate
  \draw (-0.1cm,0cm) -- (-0.2cm,0cm);  %unteres Ende der Ordinate
  \draw (-0.1cm,4.5cm) -- (-0.2cm,4.5cm) node [left] {\%};  %oberes Ende der Ordinate

  \foreach \x in {1,...,4}  %Hilfslinien
    \draw[gray!50, text=black] (-0.2 cm,\x cm) -- (15.5 cm,\x cm) 
      node at (-0.5 cm,\x cm) {\x};  %Beschriftung der Hilfslinien

    \node at (7.5cm,5cm) {Wachstumsrate des realen BIP für die zehn
                           Bevölkerungsreichsten Staaten der EU 2005};  %Überschrift

  \foreach \x/\y/\country in {0.5/4.1/Rumänien,  %\x ist Anfang der Säulen
                              2/3.7/Griechenland,  %\y ist Höhe der Säulen
                              3.5/3.5/Spanien,
                              5/3.5/Polen,
                              6.5/1.9/Großbritannien,
                              8/1.5/Niederlande,
                              9.5/1.2/Frankreich,
                              11/0.9/Deutschland,
                              12.5/0.5/Portugal,
                              14/0.1/Italien}
    {
     \draw[fill=myblue] (\x cm,0cm) rectangle (1cm+\x cm,\y cm) %die Säulen
       node at (0.5cm + \x cm,\y cm + 0.3cm) {\y}; %die Prozente über den Säulen
     \node[rotate=45, left] at (0.6 cm +\x cm,-0.1cm) {\country}; %Säulenbeschriftung
    };

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Can you show a simple loop in a MWE? What is the loop variable etc. Best is to include a toy example that starts with `\documentclass{...}` to `\end{document}` where you have a loop idea (not necessarily fully functional) in it.

Comment: It might be a good idea to explain in a bit more detail what you're trying to do. In general, though, you could for instance use the PGF math engine (`\def\x{0.5}\pgfmathsetmacro\x{\x+0.1}`), or use dimensions (`\newlength\x
\setlength{\x}{0.5pt}
\addtolength{\x}{0.1pt}
\the\x`).

Comment: I would recommend to use the `pgfplots` package for this, instead of hand-knitting everything yourself.

Comment: The `pgfmathsetmacro` doesn't seem to work inside a loop (it is only executed once). I don't want to use `pgfplots`, because I also want to use variables in other cases -- not only in plots.

Comment: Maybe `l3float` can be of use here?

Answer (score 4):

I have to agree with Jake that the example on the linked website is probably done in the absence of [`pgfplots`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots) and in my opinion very very tedious. Moreover, reusing the data is much easier with a `pgfplotstable` solution.

Here is the TikZ version without manual entries (I've used LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX , I don't know what you are using, maybe `inputenc`)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{92dcec}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}

  \draw (0cm,0cm) -- (15.5cm,0cm);  %Abzisse
  \draw (0cm,0cm) -- (0cm,-0.1cm);  %linkes Ende der Abzisse
  \draw (15.5cm,0cm) -- (15.5cm,-0.1cm);  %rechtes Ende der Abzisse

  \draw (-0.1cm,0cm) -- (-0.1cm,4.5cm);  %Ordinate
  \draw (-0.1cm,0cm) -- (-0.2cm,0cm);  %unteres Ende der Ordinate
  \draw (-0.1cm,4.5cm) -- (-0.2cm,4.5cm) node [left] {\%};  %oberes Ende der Ordinate

  \foreach \x in {1,...,4}  %Hilfslinien
    \draw[gray!50, text=black] (-0.2 cm,\x cm) -- (15.5 cm,\x cm) 
      node at (-0.5 cm,\x cm) {\x};  %Beschriftung der Hilfslinien

    \node at (7.5cm,5cm) {Wachstumsrate des realen BIP für die zehn
                           Bevölkerungsreichsten Staaten der EU 2005};  %Überschrift

  \foreach \y/\country[count=\x from 0] in {4.1/Rumänien,  %\x ist Anfang der Säulen
                              3.7/Griechenland,  %\y ist Höhe der Säulen
                              3.5/Spanien,
                              3.5/Polen,
                              1.9/Großbritannien,
                              1.5/Niederlande,
                              1.2/Frankreich,
                              0.9/Deutschland,
                              0.5/Portugal,
                              0.1/Italien}
    {
     \draw[fill=myblue,xshift=0.5cm] (0.5 + 1.5*\x cm,0cm) rectangle (1cm+1.5*\x cm,\y cm) %die Säulen
       node at (0.5cm + 1.5*\x cm,\y cm + 0.3cm) {\y}; %die Prozente über den Säulen
     \node[rotate=45, left] at (1.15 cm + 1.5*\x cm,-0.1cm) {\country}; %Säulenbeschriftung
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer to the question, but an example of how PGFPlots could be used for this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
Land, Wert
Rumänien, 4.1
Griechenland, 3.7
Spanien, 3.5
Polen, 3.5
Grossbritannien, 1.9
Niederlande, 1.5
Frankreich, 1.2
Deutschland, 0.9
Portugal, 0.5
Italien, 0.1
}\datatable

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[   
    x=10mm,
    ybar, bar width=6mm,
    ymin=0,
    xtick=data,
    every x tick label/.style={
        anchor=east,
        rotate=45
    },
    xticklabels from table={\datatable}{Land},
    nodes near coords,
    axis lines*=left,
    ylabel=\%, ylabel style={rotate=-90},
    title style={align=center},
    title={Wachstumsrate des realen BIP für die\\ zehn                            bevölkerungsreichsten Staaten der EU 2005}
]
\addplot [black, fill=cyan] table [col sep=comma, x expr=\coordindex] {\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't include the `pgfplots` version. Thanks!